# Creating new arrays from existing arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
fields = ["name", "team", "number", "name", "team", "number", "name", "team", "number"]
values = ["Patrick Ewing", "New York Knicks", 33, "Rik Smits", "Indiana Pacers", 45, "Bill Russell", "Boston Celtics", 6]
```

The fields will always be only name, team and number, but the number of values (i.e., number of players) will vary each time.

I want to create new arrays for each field type, so that I will get the following:

```
names = ["Patrick Ewing", "Rik Smits", "Bill Russell"]
teams = ["New York Knicks", "Indiana Pacers", "Boston Celtics"]
numbers = [33,45,6]
```

What's a good way to do this? I have tried the following, but want to know if there are other solutions that would perform better with larger arrays (up to 300). Or would the difference be negligible?

```
names = values.values_at(*(fields.each_index.select{ |i| fields[i] == "name"}))
teams = values.values_at(*(fields.each_index.select{ |i| fields[i] == "team"}))
numbers = values.values_at(*(fields.each_index.select{ |i| fields[i] == "number"}))
```

Comment: What have you tried? We prefer that this isn't just a code-writing service. That said, this looks like a job for `zip`.

Comment: Is the `fields` list always the same? This is an odd way to organize data on the way in, so if you could adjust that it might require less processing.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I tried something and posted it below. I understand why you feel that way, but I'm a newbie and like learning by seeing what other people would do while I try out a solution myself.

Comment: @tadman Yes, `fields` always the same. I do an XML query on a system which returns a bunch of result elements with the `fields` and `values` as attributes, so I put them into `fields` and `values` arrays first and go from there.

Comment: "but I'm a newbie and like learning by seeing what other people would do while I try out a solution myself." I'd suggest reading "[ask]", https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Comment: https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips

Comment: You said, "This example has 3 instances for each field type, but it can be different each time" and wish to create local variables named after the fields. Those requirements are incompatible, since you cannot create local variables dynamically.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This will be part of a method that will return instance variables. I edited the statement you quoted to clarify the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another/concise way:

```
> name, team, number = values.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose
=> name
> ["Patrick Ewing", "Rik Smits", "Bill Russell"]
=> team
> ["New York Knicks", "Indiana Pacers", "Boston Celtics"]
=> number
> [33, 45, 6]
```

The beauty of Ruby's [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) comes into play, particulary for your problem.

Comment: That is a pretty clever one-liner. Nice.

Comment: What's the difference between using `name, team, number = values.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose` and `name, team, number = values.each_slice(3).each_with_object([]) { |_, acc| acc << _ }.transpose` ?

Comment: @massaskillz, since both return the same array, the simpler of the two--the former--is preferable. vee, you should consider incorporating massaskillz' suggestion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, not sure if you saw edit made earlier today but I did include massaskillz' suggestion. Please check the last few lines in the answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. If you were writing a book you would consider suggested changes and adopt those you considered to be improvements, replacing what you had before.Consider adopting that model. If you wish, you can give credit in the revised answer or (my preference) in a comment. It seems to me that we should strive to provide the best answers, regardless of who contributes what.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one line just use `group_by` and `with_index`:

```
grouped = values.group_by.with_index {|_, i| fields[i] }
#=> {"name"=>["Patrick Ewing", "Rik Smits", "Bill Russell"],'
    "team"=>["New York Knicks", "Indiana Pacers", "Boston Celtics"],            
    "number"=>[33, 45, 6]}
```

Then you can simple produce your arrays from this hash:

```
name = grouped["name"]
#=> ["Patrick Ewing", "Rik Smits", "Bill Russell"]
```

Or just:

```
names, teams, numbers = grouped.values
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input is consistently in groups of three you can use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
values = ["Patrick Ewing", "New York Knicks", 33, "Rik Smits", "Indiana Pacers", 45, "Bill Russell", "Boston Celtics", 6]

names = [ ]
teams = [ ]
numbers = [ ]

values.each_slice(3) do |name, team, number|
  names << name
  teams << team
  numbers << number
end
```

That's not the most optimal way of organizing things. A more Ruby-oriented style would be:

```
keys = [ :name, :team, :number ]

players = values.each_slice(3).collect do |set|
  Hash[keys.zip(set)]
end
#=> [{:name=>"Patrick Ewing", :team=>"New York Knicks", :number=>33}, {:name=>"Rik Smits", :team=>"Indiana Pacers", :number=>45}, {:name=>"Bill Russell", :team=>"Boston Celtics", :number=>6}]
```

That gives you easy access to each record without having to cross-reference multiple arrays. Even if you're displaying this in a table and need the three things separately you can still do this to select out an individual value:

```
keys.each do |key|
  players.each do |player|
    print '%-20s' % player[key]
  end

  puts
end
```

That gives you output like:

```
Patrick Ewing       Rik Smits           Bill Russell        
New York Knicks     Indiana Pacers      Boston Celtics      
33                  45                  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to group the array values by their "type":

```
fields = ["name", "team", "number", "name", "team", "number", "name", "team", "number"]
values = ["Patrick Ewing", "New York Knicks", 33, "Rik Smits", "Indiana Pacers", 45, "Bill Russell", "Boston Celtics", 6]

field_values = fields.zip(values)

names = field_values.select { |f, v| f == "name" }.map(&:last)
# => ["Patrick Ewing", "Rik Smits", "Bill Russell"]

teams = field_values.select { |f, v| f == "team" }.map(&:last)
# => ["New York Knicks", "Indiana Pacers", "Boston Celtics"]

numbers = field_values.select { |f, v| f == "number" }.map(&:last)
# => [33, 45, 6]
```

Comment: `select { |f,v| f == 'name' }` might be more concise here.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: using Facets [Enumerable#map_by](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Enumerable%3Amap_by):

```
require 'facets'
names, teams, numbers = fields.zip(values).
  map_by { |field, value| [field, value] }.
  values_at("name", "team", "number")
```